# Resolving/Routing network trafic through specific interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, routing

Currently I have two network interfaces (eth, wifi).

I am looking for solution to route all traffic `*.myprivatedomain.com` through `eth` while rest of the internet goes through `wifi`.

I understand that linux kernel ip routing table works at IP address level but the IP address range is huge for `*.myprivatedomain.com`. Right now I have more than 50+ routes added and it's hard to manage the same.

All of my use cases resolve through `domain` name instead of direct IP address, is there a way to route all specific pattern network domains to be routed through interface?

Comment: You could use dnsmasq's `ipset` functionality to add domains to an ipset then you can route traffic based on that set. [Here](https://github.com/hardenedlinux/Debian-GNU-Linux-Profiles/blob/master/docs/dns/domain-name-based-routing.md) is an example that could be modified.

Comment: If "all your use cases" are e.g. HTTP, use a proxy. If "all your use cases" are "some apps use myprivatedomain, some don't", make different network namespaces for those apps. Routing based on DNS names is extremely difficult in the general case, so alternatives almost always work better. But which alternatives work depends on your actual use case, which you have not specified.